# SaveArg value used in expect_call

Tags: c++, c++14, googletest, googlemock

I have to following mocked functions

```
DoSomething(const char* par0, const char* par2)
DoSomething2(std::string);
```

I save the value from DoSomething into

std::string savedPar_;

I want to use it in DoSomething2. How can be done this ?

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething(_, _,))
                .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<1>(&savedPar_), (Return(Ok))));
       
EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething2(savedPar_,))
                .WillOnce((Return(Ok)))); 
      // has not yet the val


sut_->work();
// savedPar_ has the value
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use `SaveArg` when `DoSomething2` is called and then to compare args saved from `DoSomething` and `DoSomething2`

```
  EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething(_, _))
                .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<1>(&savedPar1_), (Return(Ok))));
       
  EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething2(_))
                .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&savedPar2_), (Return(Ok))));

  EXPECT_EQ(savedPar1_, savedPar2_);
```

Another one is to create a custom matcher that receives a pointer, like this

```
MATCHER_P(SameAs, value, PrintToString(*value)) { 
  return arg  == *value; 
}
```

and your expectations would look like this

```
  EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething(_, _))
                .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<1>(&savedPar_), (Return(Ok))));
       
  EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething2(SameAs(&savedPar_)))
                .WillOnce((Return(Ok)));
```